# What is the purpose of the @Override annotation?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

My question is very basic why we people use `@Override` annotation and what is the importance of this annotation?

In Old JDK why it not show as warning, but in latest JDK it required then Why..?

Comment: Here is discussion on the same topic [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?][1] ,seems helpful.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why

Comment: (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html)[This link might help you]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void bar(String x, String y) {}
}

public class Foo2 extends Foo
{
    public void bar(String x, Object y) {}
}
```

You *really* meant `Foo2.bar` to override `Foo.bar`, but due to a mistake in the signature, it doesn't. If you use `@Override` you can get the compiler to detect the fault. It *also* indicates to any *reading* the code that this is overriding an existing method or implementing an interface - advising them about current behaviour and the possible impact of renaming the method.

Additionally, your compiler may give you a warning if a method overrides a method *without* specifying `@Override`, which means you can detect if someone has added a method with the same signature to a superclass without you being aware of it - you may not *want* to be overriding the new method, as your existing method may have different semantics. While `@Override` doesn't provide a way of "un-overriding" the method, it at least highlights the potential problem.

Answer (score 6):

Just to make sure at compile time that we are really overriding the method, also adds good amount to the readability of code

[`@Override`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) is there since JDK 1.5, so you might get warning in prior

Answer (score 2):

Using this annotation you may be sure that you are really overriding base method, not creating new one (e.g., by accidentally using wrong arguments). If you use `@Override` annotation, you will get compile time error if something is not right.

Comment: I donot get any compile time error, please let me know , what did I miss [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191807/use-of-override-annotation-in-custom-listener-class-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 1):

To verify during compile time that you are actually overriding a method. IDE's can tell you immediately when you provide that annotation.