# What's the point of @Override annotation in Java 1.6

Tags: java, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

I keep running into incompatibility problems due to this annotation. What's the point of having it anyway?

What's the difference between simply overriding a method and overriding a method + annotating it with @override?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why

Comment: A similar post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076008/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-override-annotation

Answer (score 4):

To quote from the `@Override` JavaDoc:

> If a method is annotated with this annotation type but does not override a superclass method, compilers are required to generate an error message.

So a good answer would be "to prevent potential run time errors at compile time" :-)

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

The point is to launch an error if you are not really overriding a method.

For example, you have

```
public class SuperClass {
  public void doSomething(int a) {
  }
}
```

You may make an error while extending it

```
public class SubClass {
  public void doSomething(String a) {
  }
}
```

Now do you believe you have reimplemented the superclass method but you have just added a new one.

Add `@Override` before the method declaration and a error will be shown, so you know there is something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It make it clear that a method should override a parent's method.

If you are having trouble it suggests you are make many incompatible changes in parent classes (without getting your IDE to do this for you) or you are compiling the code with Java 5.0 which doesn't allow this annotation if you are implementing an interface.